# How do I read a file from a package - something like a resource bundle in Java

Tags: java, deployment, file, installation, io

I have a words.txt file that I have put in a particular java package and would need to read it from that same location. I do not control the deployment, so I don't know where the packages will be deployed.

Example location:  com/example/files/words.txt .

I know how to use the ResourceBundle class to read properties file from the package hierarchy rather than a relative/absolute path. like *ResourceBundle.getBundle(com.example.files.words)*  Is there something similar for general files so that I can read it from the package hierarchy rather than some absolute/relative path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `getResourceAsStream()` method (defined at class `Class`) to retrieve resources from the class-path. If class `WordReader` is located in package `com.example` then the path to the resource file should be `files/words.txt`

```
package com.example;

public class WordReader {

   public void readWords() {
     InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("files/words.txt");
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     for(Scanner sc = new Scanner(is); sc.hasNext(); )  
         sb.append(sc.nextLine()).append('\n');

     String content = sb.toString();
   }
}
```

Comment: Looks promising but is this how you do this? This should be a pretty common problem with deployments. I am just wondering if this is the best practice for it.