# FileNotFoundException being thrown even though text file is within package?

Tags: java

Program throws `FileNotFoundException` even though file being referenced is clearly within the same package. I've included all the necessary packages (    `import java.io.BufferedReader; import java.io.File; import java.io.FileNotFoundException; import java.io.FileReader; import java.io.IOException;`) and have implemented `BufferedReader` and `FileReader` classes correctly so I'm not sure what the issue is:

```
public class TryWithResources {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("test.txt");

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Can't find file " + file.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to read file " + file.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `test.txt` has to be in the same directory as the `.jar` file. You can further verify the issue by using an absolute path to the file temporarily.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the advice it worked! Why exactly won't it recognize the file within the package containing the class running the script?

Comment: here is another question where you can see an example how to read a file from within a java package http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036836

Comment: Text files have nothing to do with packages. They live in directories, not in packages. The fact that packages are  organized in directory hierarchies may confuse you. But when you run an application, the current directory is where you started the application, not anything relating to packages.

Comment: @stazima No, it has to be in the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

you want `getResourceAsStream` instead of `File` and `FileReader`.

`File` is for opening files from the filesystem. `getResourceAsStream` is for opening files from your package (or from the jar file if you deploy).

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.txt");
```

here is good information https://www.novixys.com/blog/read-file-resources-folder-java/